# Applying horizontal cards in SLDS

Tags: visualforce, slds

I'm trying to display the slds cards horizontally. But it is displaying vertically.Following is the screenshot of my output.[image].Why is it not displaying horizontal tiles??Can anyone help?

```
<br></br>
        <apex:repeat value="{!eve_n}" var="eve" >
        <br></br> 
            <ul class="slds-list--horizontal slds-has-cards--space has-selections">
                 <li class="slds-list__item">              
                    <div class="slds-tile slds-tile--board">
                       <p class="slds-tile__title slds-truncate"> 
                           <apex:outputLink value="{!gotoPage}" id="link1">
                                        <apex:param name="eid" value="{!eve.id}" />
                                                 {!eve.name}
                           </apex:outputLink>
                       </p>
                       <p class="slds-tile__title slds-truncate"> 
                           <apex:outputText >Category : {!eve.Category__c}  </apex:outputText>
                       </p>
                       <p class="slds-tile__title slds-truncate"> 
                           <apex:outputText >Duration : {!eve.Duration__c} hours  </apex:outputText>
                       </p> 
                    </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
         </apex:repeat>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like your repeat tag may be in the wrong place.  You're repeating the entire ul elemement, and not the li inside the ul.  Try placing the repeat tag inside the ul tag?

If that doesn't work, you could always use slds-grid instead.

Comment: thanks @Jason Benkert. I put the repeat tag in wrong place as you said.Its working now.